# textarea + R variable getting an extra space

Tags: html, r, shiny, textarea

I use textarea (HTML) in my Shiny app.

When I put a R variable  inside im geeting an extra space
for example:

```
HTML("<textarea id='aa' dir='ltr' style='font-size: 15px; name='aa' rows='12' cols='80'>hey</textarea><br><br>") #working well

x = "hey"
HTML("<textarea id='aa' dir='ltr' style='font-size: 15px; name='aa' rows='12' 
cols='80'>",x,"</textarea><br><br>") #not working well - i'm getting " hey"
```

any idea?

Comment: Try `HTML(..., .noWS = "outside"`), noWS stands for no white space. Instead of "outside" you can use "before" or "after" (outside combines both).

Comment: like this: HTML("<textarea id='aa' dir='ltr' style='font-size: 15px; name='aa' rows='12' 
cols='80', .noWS = 'outside>",x,"</textarea>")  ? it doesn't work

Comment: like this: `HTML("<textarea id='aa' dir='ltr' style='font-size: 15px; name='aa' rows='12' cols='80'>",x,"</textarea>", .noWS = "outside")`  ... .noWS is an argument to the function `HTML()`, not part of its HTML-text argument.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would we to wrap in `paste0`:

```r
library(shiny)

x <- "hey"

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML(
    paste0("<textarea id='aa' dir='ltr' style='font-size: 15px; name='aa' rows='12' cols='80'>", x, "</textarea><br><br>")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3509
```

[image]